# Replacing all 0s with Nulls in a table

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database, sql-function, azure-sql

Is there a way to replace all 0s with a null for all the columns of a table ? I know how to do it for single column, I am searching for something like dynamic query for all the columns.

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

You can write one `update` query, but you need to list all columns:

```
update t
    set col1 = nullif(col1, 0),
        col2 = nullif(col2, 0),
        . . . ;
```

You might want to add:

```
where col1 = 0 or col2 = 0 or . . .
```

To limit the number of rows that are processed.

Comment: This can work, thanks but doesnt answer my question. I was looking for some dynamic way to execute for the whole table with 50+ columns and similarly for multiple tables

Comment: @Shadow . . . At least part of your question was on how to avoid multiple `update`s.

Comment: Yes that is correct, let me update my question

Comment: @Shadow . . . Better you should ask a *new* question rather than editing one that has already been answered.

Comment: I accept that the previous version was ambiguous, I have clearified it now.

Comment: @Shadow you can copy paste the column names 50 times manually. Probably will be faster than creating a dynamic query. I think this answer is proper for the question, it could help a future person searching for it. If you need help creating a dynamic query, you should create a question for "How can you create a dynamic query to replace all 0's with nulls on all columns of a table", and put the code that you've created so far there, so people can help you.

Comment: Copy pasting 50 columns for a single table and then doing it for all the tables is not the solution I asked.